# "if else" statement inside a trigger on sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

While learning java I made a simple income tax calc app, you input the income (salary) and it returned the subsidy and the final salary after tax,both of them were fixed values, I used "if else" statements like these

```
if(salary > 0.01 && salary < 644.58){
            final = (salary - 0.01) * 0.01 + 0;
            subsidy = 50.65;
        }else if(salary > 644.59 && salary < 5470.92){
            final  = (salary - 644.59) * 0.06 + 12.38;
            subsidy = 856.98;
        }else if(salary > 5470.93 && salary < 9614.66){
            final = (salary - 5470.93) * 0.10 + 321.26;
            subsidy = 1148.76;
        }
```

Now I'm trying to do this on sql using phpmyadmin, I have a table with the following columns: ID, employee name, salary, subsidy and final salary.

Now what I want is that when I insert or update a employee and it's salary it automatically fills or changes the subsidy and the final salary columns based on certain parameters, basically like the "else if" code I posted above but in sql when entering data on a table.

I know that it can be done with triggers but I don't really know how to achieve this, I also don't know if I'm supposed to use a trigger for every "else if" constraint or if I can do every salary constraint on a single trigger similar to the java code I posted.

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. If you need the salary including tax, you can always query it and get the **right** result, even for the then valid tax rate. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: Imagine that you set some `salary` to some row, and calculate/set `final` and `subsidy`. Is  it possible that `final` and/or `subsidy` values will be altered in future "by hands", without `salary` change? or these columns values always matches provided formula strictly?